# tests for a downloadable OpenShift cartridge

Tags: openshift

Has anyone developing a downloadable OpenShift cartridge written automated tests? I'm trying to figure out what the best way to go about that is. All the cartridges I look at don't have any mention of tests in their repositories. Are they generally simple enough that people don't bother?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we do not write tests for the cartridges.  For official Red Hat OpenShift cartridges, whenever there are new ones or updates they go through a QE process and are tested by Engineers.  I am curious if you have thoughts on what you would test and how though.

Comment: Create an app (from WAR, EAR, source, if it's a java app for example), test that it's running. Update the app, test that the change is reflected in the running app. Maybe test that markers supported by the cartridge or hooks are have having an effect. Stuff like that. One idea would be to use the java client and write junit tests for this, but that potentially seems like more effort than it's worth.